# how to sort recycler view items in android in decending order

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

MY main page:
I want to sort the recycler view when clicked on sort button

This is Expected to happen (
when sort button is clicked:
case1:if recycler is not sorted .......then it must be sorted in assending order
case2:if recycler is not sorted in assending order.......then it must be sorted in decending order
case1:if recycler is not sorted in decending order.......then it must be sorted in assending order
)

```
package edmt.dev.androidgridlayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

import edmt.dev.androidgridlayout.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter.CategoryAdapter;
import edmt.dev.androidgridlayout.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter.FeaturedAdapter;
import edmt.dev.androidgridlayout.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter.FeaturedHelperClass;
import edmt.dev.androidgridlayout.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter.ProductAdapter;

public class AllProductPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView productrecycler;
    ProductAdapter productAdapter;
    LinearLayout sortbtn,filterbtn;
    private String[] mArrayNames=new String[]{"Pizza","Burger","Wraps","Sandwich","Chicken combos","Veg combos","Majitos","Breveges"};
    ArrayList<FeaturedHelperClass> products;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_product_page);

        productrecycler = findViewById(R.id.product_recycler);
        sortbtn = findViewById(R.id.sort_btn);
        filterbtn = findViewById(R.id.filter_btn);
        productrecycler();
        sortbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sortArray();
//                sortArrayList();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sortArray() {
        Collections.sort(products);
        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    private void sortArrayList() {
        Collections.sort(products, new Comparator<FeaturedHelperClass>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(FeaturedHelperClass o1, FeaturedHelperClass o2) {
                return o1.getTitle().compareTo(o2.getTitle());
            }
        });
        productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    private void productrecycler() {
        productrecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        productrecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.yarnbg2, "Pizza", "sdffsb",400));
        products.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.yarnbg2, "Burger", "sdffsb",600));
        products.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.yarnbg2, "Wraps", "sdffsbsfavs sdvv sbdfb ",550));
        products.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.yarnbg2, "Sandwich", "sdffsbsfavs sdvv sbdfb ",300));
        products.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.yarnbg2, "Chicken combos", "sdffsbsfavs sdvv sbdfb ",900));
        products.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.yarnbg2, "Veg combos", "sdffsbsfavs sdvv sbdfb ",100));
        products.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.yarnbg2, "Majitos", "sdffsbsfavs sdvv sbdfb ",250));
        products.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.yarnbg2, "Breveges", "sdffsbsfavs sdvv sbdfb ",600));
        productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(products);
        productrecycler.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        productAdapter.setOnItemClickedListner(new ProductAdapter.onItemClickListner() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ProductAdapter" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onHeartClicked(int position ,String state) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onHeartClicked" + position+"  "+state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

My Helper Class:
Here I have implemented the Comparable interface and Compared the price of product to sort them in assending order.

But I am unable to Sort the price in decending order

How Can I achieve it?

```
package edmt.dev.androidgridlayout.HelperClasses.HomeAdapter;

public class FeaturedHelperClass implements Comparable<FeaturedHelperClass>{
    int image;
    String title;
    String Description;
    int price;

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public FeaturedHelperClass(int image, String title, String description) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.Description = description;
    }
    public FeaturedHelperClass(int image, String title, String description,int price) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.Description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public FeaturedHelperClass(int image, String title) {
        this.image = image;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        Description = description;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(FeaturedHelperClass o) {
        return this.price -o.getPrice();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to sort recyclerView by name?

Comment: no sir,I want to sort recycler view by price(int value)

Comment: I have write code for you in answer please update me It's working or not

Comment: No sir,It doesn't work in case when we try to sort in desending order.

Comment: please refer my answer

Comment: change `lhs` and `rhs` with each other

Comment: Your answer is changing only `recyclerView` sorting in your answer sorting is not by price or etc it may also can give you some problem in future but in my method sorting will always done by price

Comment: Yes sir,you are right.But my need is only to change the recycler view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort list. After sorting just submit list to adapter. 
here is [link](https://www.journaldev.com/16094/java-collections-sort) how to use sorting

Answer (score 0):

This is example code for sorting

```
Collections.sort(yourLists, new Comparator<YourList>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(YourList lhs, YourList rhs) {
            return lhs.getId().compareTo(rhs.getId());
        }
    });
```

Hope it will work!

Thankew! Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Java Collections.reverseOrder

By default, Collection.sort performs the sorting in ascending order. If we want to sort the elements in reverse order we could use following methods:
reverseOrder(): Returns a Comparator that imposes the reverse of natural ordering of elements of the collection.
reverseOrder(Comparator cmp): Returns a Comparator that imposes reverse ordering of the specified comparator.
Here are the examples for both these methods

```
Collections.sort(products,Collections.reverseOrder());
```